# Non seulement... mais (aussi) : surenchère et opposition, avec ou sans adverbe après la conjonction ?

Tags: conjonctions, adverbes, locutions

On [voit](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=solum) que quelqu'un comme Cicéron employait *non [solum](https://books.google.com/books?id=WY2Nhc3HY3sC&lpg=PA262&dq=non%20solum%20..%20sed%20etiam&pg=PA262#v=onepage&q=non%20solum%20..%20sed%20etiam&f=false)... sed etiam* (non seulement... mais aussi), ainsi que *non solum... sed* (non seulement... mais). Au TLFi on remarque que dans ce contexte d'opposition ou de gradation positive avec *non [seulement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/seulement)*, le deuxième terme est fréquemment coordonné avec *mais* (mais encore, mais aussi, mais même, mais en outre, mais en plus, mais également). Larousse a deux entrées : l'[une](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/non/54838/locution?q=non%20seulement#16001820) traitant l'opposition avec *non seulement... mais encore(aussi)*, et l'[autre](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/encore/29244/locution?q=non%20seulement#16001690) indiquant l'opposition et le renforcement avec *non seulement... mais encore*. La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=non%20seulement&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) en relève trois (...mais encore/aussi/en outre) au titre de la *surenchère*. Le LBU14 (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, §§ 1027, 1029) note qu'en l'absence de second terme pour l'opposition, on utilise *pas seulement* au lieu de *non seulement*, alors que *non* n'est pas remplaçable quand *non seulement* est *en tête* d'une sous-phrase qui s'oppose à une autre et on propose l'exemple :

> (A) Non seulement elle le supporte, mais elle l'aime.

Il m'apparaît difficile d'ajouter *aussi* ici et je ne sais pas exactement pourquoi (...*mais elle l'aime aussi*, comme quelqu'un d'autre l'aime ?? ; ...*mais aussi elle l'aime*, bizarre ? ; ...*mais l'aime-t-elle aussi*, demanderait une inversion du verbe au premier terme pour être usuel ?).

---

On peut explorer des variantes de présentation du premier et du deuxième terme :

> (1) Non seulement le meilleur, mais aussi le plus abordable.
> (2) Non
>   seulement le meilleur, mais le plus abordable.
> (3) C'est non
>   seulement le meilleur, mais c'est aussi le plus abordable.
> (4) C'est
>   non seulement le meilleur, mais aussi le plus abordable.
> (5) C'est
>   non seulement le meilleur, mais le plus abordable.
> (6)
>   C'est pas seulement le meilleur, c'est le plus abordable !

On a employé *cela est*, différemment d'avec (A). On n'est pas nécessairement plus éclairé...

---

- En quoi consiste la différence entre l'emploi de la locution en
  *opposition* et l'emploi en *surenchère* et est-ce relié à la syntaxe, à l'adverbe qui suit la conjonction *mais*, à la sémantique ou s'agit-il du même concept qu'on aborde différemment ?

  - À quoi ressemblerait un emploi marquant exclusivement l'*opposition*  et non la surenchère ?
- Y a-t-il une différence entre la tournure *non seulement... mais* sans adverbe, et 
  celle suivie d'un adverbe (*aussi, encore*), ou la première n'est-elle que la deuxième par ellipse de celui-ci ?
- L'ajout de *aussi* dans (A) changerait-il le sens et
  affaiblirait-il même l'idée de surenchère ; pourquoi ça semble moins important avec (1-6), le cas échéant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour la première question : par sa construction, *Non seulement... mais...* est une opposition, mais au sens que peut avoir *non... mais...* dans d'autres usages. "Il faut parler à son interlocuteur *non* comme à un inférieur ou un supérieur *mais* comme à un égal". *Non* ce qui est faux, *mais* ce qui est vrai.

La tournure *non seulement... mais...* utilise donc le gabarit de l'opposition *non... mais...* pour en faire une surenchère. 
Dans l'exemple (A), ce qui est faux = "*seulement* elle le supporte" (tournure qui, hors de la locution *non seulement*, est incorrecte, mais dont le sens est clair : elle ne fait que le supporter), ce qui est vrai = en plus de le supporter, elle l'aime.

On passe de "*non* ce qui est faux, *mais* ce qui est vrai" à "*non seulement* ce qui est vrai, *mais* ce qui est vrai aussi". Un emploi exprimant purement l'opposition se passerait tout simplement donc de *seulement*, *uniquement* et de leurs cousins pour ne garder que *non... mais...*.

Pour la deuxième question, l'adverbe *aussi, encore, en plus...* est purement optionnel et ne change pas grand chose au sens. Il ajoute tout au plus de l'emphase. "Non seulement elle le supporte, mais *en plus* elle l'aime !" exprime bien plus l'incrédulité ou l'étonnement que "Non seulement elle le supporte, mais elle l'aime."

Enfin, ajouter *aussi* dans (A) affaiblirait peut-être le sens (en fait, je trouverais surtout la phrase maladroite), mais *en plus* est tout à fait à sa place. Cela tient peut-être à l'ambiguïté du sens de *aussi* qui peut sous-entendre qu'elle l'aime en plus d'autres personnes. Dans les autres exemples, cette ambiguïté n'est pas présente : *c'est aussi le plus abordable*, même si on sous-entend *c'est* par ellipse, est tout à fait clair : *aussi* se rapporte forcément aux autres qualités du produit, pas à un autre produit qui serait aussi abordable. Ce dernier point me semble toutefois assez subjectif.

Comment: Vraiment bon. Merci ! A-t-on une idée du pourquoi des deux entrées au Larousse ?

Comment: Il y a une entrée dans "non" et une dans "encore" et les deux définitions sont valables, selon le sens qu'on donne à "opposition", donc je suppose qu'ils ont simplement ajouté le même usage aux deux mots sans vérifier la cohérence de leurs définitions.